# "The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_15/concat:0", shape=(884758, 1), dtype=float64)]" Error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, concatenation

I have the following code where I am trying to combine a set of 22 3D images of size (96, 96, 96) with its corresponding test value (shown as input_tmt) of (for example) 50. In other words, I would like one image to have a test value of 50 while another to have a test value of 80. I am able to run my images through the CNN, but I am stuck on the concatenation layer.

I have tried to change both input values into 1D tensors which are (884736,1) for the images and (22,1) for the test values and tried to concatenate them, but I am receiving the error **The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_15/concat:0", shape=(884758, 1), dtype=float64)**

I have been on this problem for over 2 days now and would appreciate any help/resources where it can be solved. Thank you

```
batch_size = 2

input_tmt = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.asarray([50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50., 50.,
                                             80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80., 80.]).reshape([22, 1]))
input_images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image.flatten().reshape([884736, 1]))
print(type(input_images), input_images.shape, type(input_tmt), input_tmt.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu',
                     input_shape=[96, 96, 96, 1]))
model.add(Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(concatenate([input_images, input_tmt], axis = 0))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=15)
eval = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
print(eval)
```

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing the use of the functional and sequential APIs, that will not work, what exactly should this concatenate call in the middle of your model do?

Comment: Apologies, but I am not that familiar with the concatenation function. I hope to "label" each image with its corresponding test value by combining the input_images array with the input_tmt array and let the program use both the images and test values to train.

Comment: Ahh, I have understood my mistake. I will create a functional Model for the concatenation and try to figure it out using that. Thank you for your help